# Amazon Cognito Javascript with developer authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, amazon-web-services, user-registration, amazon-cognito

I would like to use a third party service to manage my user registration (dailycred). Is there a way to integrate this with Amazon Cognito using javascript.

From what I gather from here:
https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en

There needs to be some backend coding to transfer the tokens around. Is there a way to do this with something like dailycred (https://www.dailycred.com)?? If not is there a cheap alternative??